# HtmlAgilityPack if div exists

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using Html Agility Pack to see if divs with a specific class and id exist.

```
 string target = "http://192.168.3.230/index.htm";
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 string html = client.DownloadString(target);
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(html);

 if (doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='bit0' and @class='rledoff']") != null){
      //actions in here
 }

 else if (doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='bit0' and @class='rledon']") != null)
 {
      //actions in here
 }
```

Currently the else if should be true, but it is doing the actions in the if statement.
I have seen this work correctly when I did

`doc.Load("c:\\somelocaldest\\page.htm");`

When I try to do it from the actual site instead of a locally saved file of the site it will see that the id is correct and disregard the class. What could cause it to behave differently between getting the html for a local file and from an external site/device?

Comment: Try to look at what's going on the wire using a tool such as Fiddler. There can be many contextual differences (encoding, user agent, headers, redirects, cookies, referral, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all I suggest you to do this, for me it worked faster than WebClient.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(target);
```

If you say that this works on local hmtl file and not work when the html is on the server, then do the following.

```
File.WriteAllText(path,doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
```

Sometimes the source code of page its differ when you download it with htmlweb (or webclient) so make again your xpath by using this new html file.

Comment: You were right. It is downloading what I believe to be the page as it is when it comes from the server. The classes I'm looking for are then changed via jquery as it gets the status back from the server. What I am reading is whether leds are on or off, so by default they're all off, then when it gets the status it then turns them on as needed. I need to grab the page in its current state.

Comment: I glad that I could help you :) I was facing this problem many times.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to pull it as it is. I was thinking of putting it in a webBrowser and taking the document text from that. As of now that isn't working.

Comment: I think its better to rewrite your xpath, its much easier and your program will be faster. If the output of new html is confusing for you then use html beautifier to make the html more readable. You can find many html beautifiers, just google it.

Comment: Reading the html isn't the problem. It's getting the right html that is. Everything I'm doing is giving me html with all the leds off when I know some of them are on.

Comment: I have another solution for you but its pointless for me but I think you will like it. If you scrapping a popular page you can scrap from google cache: `http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:yourwebsite.com` but beware its may be outdated

Comment: It's on a device that isn't coming from the web. I'm communicating with it via ethernet. This page isn't on the web.